# HTTP Token Login & perform the token

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

This is my HTTP code. But there's some problem with my code. I'm not sure is the decoding part or getting data part. What I want to do is get the token value.

```
func login(account: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void){
            
            
            guard let url = URL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:8080/login") else{
                fatalError("URL is not defined")
            }
            
            let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", account, password)
            let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
            
            
            let user = UserLogin(account: account, password: password)
            
            var request=URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
                (data, response, error) in
                guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return; }
                
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                    return
                }
                
                guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserToken.self, from: data)else{
                    completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials(errorMessage: "can't decode")))
                    return
                }
                
                
                let statusCode = httpURLResponse.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200{
                    let token = loginResponse.value
                    completion(.success(token))
                }else{
                    completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials(errorMessage: "invalid")))
                }
                
    
            }.resume()
        }
```

And this is my user token model

```
import Foundation



struct UserToken: Codable{
    var id: UUID?
    var value: String
    var expireTime: Date?
    var user: UserLogin?
}
```

This is my user login model:

```
import Foundation

struct UserLogin:Codable{
    var id: UUID?
    var account: String
    var password: String
}
```

And this is the format of getting the user token json:
[image]

When I use the simulator , the error says "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Dating_Login.AuthenticationError error 1.)"

And I'm using the private func to print it.

```
private func UserLogin(){
                
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                HTTPUser().login(account: number, password: pass){result in
                    switch result{
                    case .success(let token):
                        defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "value")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.isin = true
                            print(token)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the decoding would fail, `expireTime` - although it's formatted as a date, it's type is a string. Changing your model to the following should work.

On another note on your `UserLogin` model the `id` again can be an optional string same on the `UserToken` model. All properties on the `UserLogin` model will need to be optional as only `id` is on the response.

```
struct UserToken: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var value: String
    var expireTime: String?
    var user: User?
}

struct UserLogin: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var account: String?
    var password: String?
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. But it seems that is not the problem. The data I get should be as same as the model right?

Comment: @蔡濡安 I've just updated my answer, that should work now.

Comment: It really works. So does the data come from json is all String?

Comment: Yes all data from the JSON comes as String. Anything in Double Quotes will be a string being returned.

Comment: @Asad got it. Thanks.

Comment: @蔡濡安 If this solved your issue can you mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Owen26 Oops , I'm sorry about that.